# chef server 12.6 disable webui

Tags: chef-infra

I am using Chef Server 12.6.0 and wish to disable the webui.
How do I go about doing that?

I tried adding `chef_server_webui['enable'] = false` to `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb`, but when I did `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` things broke.

I was able to get things back to normal by removing the above line and re-running configure.

```
Recipe Compile Error in /var/opt/opscode/local-mode-cache/cookbooks/private-chef/recipes/default.rb
=============================================================================
RuntimeError
------------
Error loading file: /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb:4:in `from_file':     
  undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Isn't the webui (aka. [Chef Manage](https://docs.chef.io/manage.html)) a premium feature in Chef Server 12.x that you have to [install explicitly](https://docs.chef.io/install_server.html)? Did you install that before?

Comment: Let's say it's already installed, do I just uninstall it?

Comment: Are you really sure that you are running Chef Server 12.6? If it is blue and looks like [this](http://railsware.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/precise64.png), you're not running version 11.

Comment: Black and white , not blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uninstall the previously installed Chef Manage feature by issuing the following command:

```
# chef-manage-ctl uninstall
```

See also its [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_manage.html#uninstall).

Comment: @Seth: it looks like you're missing the second `a` in man`a`ge

Comment: You can also uninstall the package via your system package manager, most of the `uninstall` ctl command is just that.

Comment: That seems like you had an old version of chef-manage installed? But glad that it finally worked.